# Querying player data in GameSparks returns 0 results

Tags: mongodb, nosql, gamesparks

I want to get all players in GameSparks data with an email field. I can Query in Data Explorer, but when I tried it in CloudCode it does not work.

In [GameSparks documentation](https://docs.gamesparks.com/api-documentation/cloud-code-api/cloud-data/sparkmongocollectionreadonly.html) I found this:

```
var results = Spark.metaCollection('metatest').find({"metatest1" : {"$gt" : 1}});
```

I replaced it with this:

```
var results = Spark.metaCollection('player').find({"email":{"$exists":"true"}});
```

When I trying to get the count of 'results' it returns 0.

What am I doing wrong? Is it impossible to access the MongoDB entries for any of the System Collections defined by GameSparks (like 'player', 'challengeInstance' etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`systemCollection`** instead of `metaCollection`.